# Strip Devise Email to just first letter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

What I'm trying to accomplish is a button in my navigation menu with the first letter of your email, but leaving the database email field as is.

e.g. If my email was 'test@test.com' in the navigation bar it would have 'T'.

I have a default Devise setup, but no clue where to even start.

Any help would be brilliant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view:

```
<%= current_user.email[0].upcase %>
```

Comment: What would be the best controller to put this in?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Brilliant and Simple